# C# Convertir a datetime 00:60:00

Tags: c#

Tengo un cronómetro con este código:

```
private void cronometro_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    seg++;
    if(seg == 60)
    {
        min++;
        seg = 0;
    }
    else if (min == 60)
    {
        hr++;
        min = 0;
    }
    str_crono = hr.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + ":" + min.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + ":" + seg.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');
       label7.Text = str_crono;

}
```

tras esto, intento desglosar para convertir todo el tiempo del crono a segundos con este código:

```
DateTime conversionlabel = System.Convert.ToDateTime(str_crono);

int hh = conversionlabel.Hour;
int mm = conversionlabel.Minute;
int ss = conversionlabel.Second;
```

El inconveniente es que cuando `str_crono` es igual a: 00:60:00 me lanza este error:

> La cadena representa un DateTime no admitido en el calendario System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.**

Alguna idea? qué estoy haciendo mal?
Gracias!!

Comment: Obviamente, `00:60:00` no existe como datetime. Debería pasar de `00:59:59` a `01:00:00`. El problema probablemente es que en tu cronometro estás comprobando si el minuto es `60` en un `else if`. Deberían ser 2 `if` consecutivos.

Comment: Mil gracias por tu respuesta pero no lo tengo claro, ¿ serías tan amable de corregir mi cronómetro? Por favor.

Comment: Simplemente, en tu cronometro, prueba a quitar el `else`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay muchas formas de implementar un cronómetros, pero le dejo una sencilla donde el tiempo lo controla una variable de tipo datetime, a la cual simplemente se le van sumando segundos en cada tick del timer

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Ejemplos
{
    class Crono
    {
        System.Timers.Timer tmr;
        DateTime tiempo;

        public Crono()
        {
            tmr = new System.Timers.Timer();
            tmr.Interval = 1000; // Se ejecutará una vez por segundo.
            tmr.Elapsed += Tmr_Elapsed;

        }

        public void Iniciar()
        {
            tmr.Start();
            tiempo = new DateTime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        private void Tmr_Elapsed(object sender,     System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
        tiempo = tiempo.AddSeconds(1);

        Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}:{2}",
                         tiempo.Hour.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'),
                         tiempo.Minute.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'),
                         tiempo.Second.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0'));
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            Crono c = new Crono();
            c.Iniciar();
            Console.WriteLine("Presiona una tecla para finalizar");
            Console.ReadKey();

        }

    }
}
```